# Put a value out of a http request in swift

Tags: ios, swift

To create a `UITableView` I have to initialize the number of rows, and in my case it depends on an HttpRequest (Sent with the Framework HttpSwift). My problem is that I can't output the number on the return of my request

```swift
request.GET("/media/", parameters: nil, completionHandler:{
    (response: HTTPResponse) in
        if let err = response.error {
            println("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return //also notify app of failure as needed
        }
        if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var user = Medias(JSONDecoder(data))
            var nbRows:Int = user.medias.count
        }
})

println(nbRows) //NbRows don't have a value out of the request

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nbRows
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the request is performed in a background thread and the execution continues sequentially. Then when you do `println(nbRows)` the nbRows variable is not updated as the request has not been made yet or is being made.

So to fix this, make nbRows a global variable and then reload the tableView when the variable is set.

Use the following code:

```
request.GET("/media/", parameters: nil, completionHandler: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
            if let err = response.error {
                println("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return //also notify app of failure as needed
            }
            if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
                let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                //println(str)
                var user = Medias(JSONDecoder(data))
                self.nbRows = user.medias.count   // make nbRows a globalVariable
                println(nbRows)
                // need to update tableView in the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    // reload the tableView
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        })

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nbRows
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for your answer, I wil read some tutorials on the threads ;)